# Require local file in PHPUnit

Tags: phpunit

I am trying to test our source tree using PHPUnit with old, web based legacy code, trying to make as few changes as possible to begin.  Once testing is in place, I can then change the library functions for better use, and better unit testing. However, I need the tests done to allow me to change it.

Question:  We share the library code across many projects of our application, but they all share a common directory structure.  When the website runs, local directories are available when we require files in the library.

Consider this:

```
APP1
APP2
Library
Library/COMM
Library/UTIL
...
```

When you launch the application, you point to either APP1 or APP2 for the different applications.  They have the common code (messaging, DB access, etc...). in Library.  The problem is, that the functions in the library need special parameters to work, as they are coded today.  These libraries simply require('Config.php'); since it will be found in either APP1 or APP2 (they both have one with application specific settings) and the web server is using the APP1 or APP2 as the directory when the Library files were require()'d.

While this works, it fails when attempting to run the code in PHPUnit.  My question is how to include the Config.php file without having to change the legacy code too much before the testing is in place.

I know this is the wrong format, but this is what I inherited.

I can not simply require('../../APP1/Config.php'); since both applications share this library.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Note: We are trying to test the library and all projects as we begin writing tests, so not sure if the include_path will solve it.  I am contemplating different PHPUnit.xml.dist files for each application, but trying to avoid this right now due to corporate influence of testing all applications right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From phpunit.xml (<phpunit bootstrap="./bootstrap.php">...) and from the cli (--bootstrap ./bootstrap.php) you can specify a bootstrap file. In that file you could do this inclusion you are looking to do.

As word of advice, when stating to test a legacy code base don't start with Unit test. Your first goal should be "get some kind of automated tests in place". For most people, this will be system tests. That is testing the stack/site as a whole. A common tools for this is [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

This is still not small task. What you are going to have to do it work out "how do I put my system in to a consistent state". The first thing you may need to do is automate importing and emptying test data in your database. Once you can do that you will be able to reliably run automated tests. You will need to get many other things to be consistent also, date and times being a good example.

My point is that, from experience, starting with Unit tests will not give you the value you need to prove that automated testings is worth the effort.

Good luck!

Comment: I saw the bootstrap, but the internal code calls these includes, which are not valid because of pathing in the directories.  When you run in the web server, the current directory is still present, so require('Config.php'); will find the file under APP1 or APP2, which ever was launched.  I am not sure how the bootstrap you mention is going to help this, as the base code needs to still include these files when it executes.  I guess I will need different files (bootstrap and phpunit.xml) for the projects. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are trying to test both apps at the same time or not, so here are some suggestions. Where the apps include the Config.php change the code to "require(__DIR__.'/Config.php')". If you can't change the app and are only testing one app at a time; in the bootstrap run the chdir() function to be the public folder of the app you are testing. If you can't change that code and you are testing both apps together. Create test suites for each code base. In the test suite for each app call chdir(). This does mean you will always need to run via the tests suites.

Comment: Thanks.  That is what I have basically decided I will have to do.  I will have to write separate test suites, and bootstraps to get through this for the beginning.  Then I will change how the Config.php is loaded.  We are trying to test both applications as we were doing the lower level class tests first, so both applications could be tested.  Selenium will likely be used to test the interaction with the UI.